# What is the simplest way to update a DE column value from an email click?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is it possible to add parameters to the link to identify the DE and update a specific column?

**Ex :**

If the link is

```
www.landingpage.com/?listid=34567&customerid=1234&favouritecolour=red
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "update a specific column"?

Comment: Hi Adam, What I mean is that I have an empty column in a DE that I want to populate with inbound data. So, e.g. if I offer someone a choice of 5 things in the email, the one they select will be passed back into the DE column and update the row for that user. So what I am wondering is if this can be done by adding the 5 values behind the links within the email so they are passed back. Alternatively, would it be better to send people to a form and then have the form populate the DE somehow. I am an email marketer so was wondering if there is a simple solution that doesn't require script

Comment: Clare - please use [edit] to amend your question with the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [**Send Logging**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) in SFMC.

It will allow you to record Profile Attribute or sending Data Extension column values automatically at send time.

For example if your sending Data Extension has the following columns:

- EmailAddress
- FirstName
- LastName

...and you add `FirstName` to the **Send Log Data Extension**, the value for `FirstName` will automatically be populated in the Send Log at send time.

It also works for AMPScript variables defined in your email:

```
%%[
var @SegmentName
set @SegmentName = "Welcome Series"
]%%
```

If you had a `SegmentName` column in Send Log, the value for `SegmentName` will also be populated in the Send Log at send time.

If you want values automatically added to all email links, you can have SFMC support enable the [**Web Analytics Connector**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/).  You'll need to provide them with the parameters and values to add to every URL.

**UPDATE**

If you want to record data after the send (based on parameter values in a link), then you'd need Landing or Microsite Page that retrieves the parameter values and records them in a Data Extension.

The code on the landing page would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

    var debug = false;
    var request = {};

    if (Request.Method == "GET") {

       if (debug) {
          Write("GET<br/>");
       }

       SetVar("emailAddress", Attribute.GetValue("emailaddr")); // from subscriber context
       SetVar("customerid", Request.GetQueryStringParameter("customerid")); // from the origin URL

       // initialize the DE
       var de = DataExtension.Init("DATAEXTENSIONNAME");

       // set column values
       var row = {};
       row.customerid = request.customerid;

       try {

          // add/update the row
          SetVar("results", de.Rows.Update(row, ['emailAddress'], [request.emailAddress]));

       } catch (e) {

          SetVar("results", e);

       }

    } 

    function SetVar(varName, varValue){
        request[varName] = varValue;
        Variable.SetValue(varName, varValue);
    }

    if (debug) {
        Write("<br><br>debug output: " + Stringify(request));
    }

</script><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <br>emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%
       <br>customerid: %%=v(@customerid)=%%
    </body>
</html>
```

In you email, you'd need to build the URLs with the [micrositeURL()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/sites/MicrositeURL.html) function, so that the subscriber context is passed along.